# Problem with Ubuntu One (syncing)

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my computer. The other day I learned about [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) and signed up for the service. I placed a couple of files into my Ubuntu One folder and they were loaded to the web (which I logged into and saw). I then created a folder, placed a couple of files into it and marked the folder to sychronize with Ubuntu One. This worked as well.

However, as of last night the syncing has stopped working.  I have placed a couple of new files into the folder and I periodically get a small window at the top right of my screen saying that the file x is being uploaded to my personal cloud. The message eventually goes away, but the file is never actually uploaded. So, it did initially seem to work but isn't now. Last night I thought I saw a message on the Ubuntu One website saying that the system was down for maintenance - I can't find that message again today.

The only other thing that happened last night was that at one point I received a popup window asking me to supply login information for Amazon S3.  Although it didn't seem right, I put my Ubuntu One user ID and password into this window and told it to remember it.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry you're not alone my Ubuntu One is not working either for now.

Comment: For future reference, you can keep track of those status messages at Ubuntu One's Twitter feed: http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntuone

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on the server side because I experience the same issue right now. If you want to know what exactly Ubuntu One is doing, then start a terminal and run the following command:

```
tail -f ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log
```